# How to auto start a script in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, python

Hi  I am trying to autostart a python script  .
I have edited the rc.local file to add the file location  before exit 0..

```
sudo python /home/pi/myscript.py &
```

The myscript.py has executable permission .
But the python script doesnt run .

I have also tried to add  the file to .bashrc but when raspi is rebooted the sccript does not start .
But when i connect to raspi using putty terminal from ubuntu machine ..i get a

```
tkinter.Tclerror: no display name and no $DISPLAY environmental variable  error
```

..which is usually what get when i run the script from putty ..

Comment: As the problem and answer are essentially the same I have closed this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Don't use `sudo` in `rc.local`, init runs it with privileges anyway.  Note you can't start a graphical app that way; if you want to replace the GUI login at boot that's a complex task.  If you want to start it in a desktop session at normal login, [see here](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#Autostarted_applications_using_lxsession).  WRT `ssh`, try `export $DISPLAY=:0` but that will start the app on the display connected to the pi, not your ssh terminal.

Comment: Here's a Q&A about that: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6753/5538  If you want to go for the "complex task" mentioned above, you'll need to ask a more specific question and detail *exactly* what it is you are trying to achieve -- what the app does, where and when you want it displayed, and how this should relate to the normal login screen.

Comment: I removed the python script i wanted to autostart from rc.local ...and added it to .bashrc ...it still doesnt start the script but when i open the terminal ..the script starts on its own ..Its a python scirpt that has a gui based on Tkinter .